# Where is generated MySQL Schema located in directory structure with Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to learn Doctrine ORM association mapping in Symfony using the following reference:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

I assume that the MySQL schema will be generated after executing the entity. Is there any clue where it will located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in a general setup, it will not be stored. Which is why we use [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) in all projects.

After installation, every migration will be stored in the `migrations_directory` and you will see the generated SQL to migrate and undo.